# Is it possible to only expand the width of a responsive image?

Tags: html, css

I have a responsive image slider in my header but i would like for it to only expand the width when the viewport changes. A fixed height centered image that shows more when the viewport widens. A bit like opening curtains. Is this possible? Tried to google but not sure how to word it properly.

I'm using the carousel from bootstrap with this added code:

```
header{
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 507px;
    max-width: 1920px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    box-shadow: 0px 3px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-bottom: 7px solid #9ccb43;
}

#header-carousel{
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    max-height: 500px;
}

    .carousel-inner{
        max-height: 500px;
    }
```

and my html:

```
<header>

        <div id="header-carousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">

            <h1>Isoleren Loont</h1>




            <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">

                <div class="item active">
                    <img src="images/static/carousel/carousel-4.jpg" alt="..."> 
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/static/carousel/carousel-5.jpg" alt="...">

                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <img src="images/static/carousel/carousel-6.jpg" alt="...">
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </header>
```

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Yes, its possible if you show your code. Like Nostradamus say - use `background-image`.

Comment: @Paulie_D Very sorry, I've updated my post with my code.

Comment: @Narek-T Very sorry, I've updated my post with my code. Is it possible to use background-image with the carousel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I say, yes, this is possible. I did very quick example, but I believe, you can improve this code

Use `background-image`

[JSFiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Narek_T/89vmag6z/)

Comment: That's awesome, thanks for your time!